# Disabling a Dropdown list item jquery not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to disable the dropdown list item using jquery.
The index value is -1 and the value is  ------- Internal -------. I tried below syntaxes one by one(The solutions were the answers for similar questions). None of them are working.  Iam using IE8.

```
var value="------- Internal -------";
$("[id*='ChildOrganizationDropDownList'] option[value=" + value + "]").prop('disabled','disabled'); 
$("#ChildOrganizationDropDownList option[value=" + value + "]").prop('disabled','disabled');    
$("[id*='ChildOrganizationDropDownList']").option('------- Internal -------').prop('disabled',true);    
$("id*='ChildOrganizationDropDownList' option[value='------- Internal -------']").prop('disabled','disabled');    
$("[id*='ChildOrganizationDropDownList']").option("[value*='------- Internal -------']").prop('disabled', true);
$("[id*='ChildOrganizationDropDownList']").attr("disabled",$(_this.CustomerNameDropDownList).find("option[value='------- Internal -------']"));
```

Designer : Aspx

```
<div class="selectionControls">
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSubcontracting" runat="server" Text="Subcontracting" Enabled="true" />
  <asp:HiddenField ID="SubcontractingHiddenField" runat="server" />
  <div class="subSelectionControl" id="AllowSubcotractingSelection" style="display: none;">
    <div class="subContractingControls">
      Parent BU:
      <span>
        <div class="subContractingControls">
          Supplier <em class="mandatoryIndicator">*</em>:
          <span>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ChildOrganizationDropDownList" runat="server" Width="200px" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="IxChildOrganizationHiddenField" runat="server" />
          </span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Aspx.cs

```
public Dictionary<int, string> ChildOrganizations
        {
            set
            {
                var result = value;
                result.Add(0, "Select Supplier");
                ChildOrganizationDropDownList.DataSource = result;
                ChildOrganizationDropDownList.DataTextField = "value";
                ChildOrganizationDropDownList.DataValueField = "key";
                ChildOrganizationDropDownList.DataBind();
                ChildOrganizationDropDownList.SelectedValue = "0";


            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the html

Comment: @DarrenSweeney the designer code is added

Comment: The problem seems be in $("#ChildOrganizationDropDownList option") part. And has to be changed to some other syntax.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dZqEu/3/

Comment: after applying my correct indentation edit you will see that 1 span and 2 divs aren't closed. This could prevent javascript from running correctly... just a guess

Answer (score 3):

I used `each` and it worked for me: https://jsfiddle.net/pz9curkb/1/

```
<select id="ChildOrganizationDropDownList">
    <option value="Default">Default</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">------- Internal -------</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
</select>


 $("#ChildOrganizationDropDownList option").each(function(){   
     if($(this).text() === "------- Internal -------"){
        this.disabled  = true;
     }
});
```

Please note in this solution I used this instead of $(this), which means I used disabled option provided by javascript

Comment: @ManojNayak do you have a master page?

Answer (score 3):

First, ASP.NET might change the rendered client ID on your ChildOrganizationDropDownList control. In order to make this managable, you should set ClientIDMode to Static:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ChildOrganizationDropDownList" runat="server" Width="200px" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

(See [MSDN Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).) Now, you'll know that you can find this control using jQuery selector `$("#ChildOrganizationDropDownList")`.

Secondly, I'm not sure that your JavaScript waits for the DOM to finish loading. If it fires too early, it will not find anything (since it's not loaded yet). Use `$(document).ready(handler)`, or the shorthand `$(handler)`.

Now, a JavaScript that disables all options with value "-1" in ChildOrganizationDropDownList could look like this:

```
$(function() { // Wait for the DOM to load
  $("#ChildOrganizationDropDownList option[value='-1']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Comment: It is probably worth noting that `ClientIDMode="Static"` is "new" with .NET 4.  If the OP is using a earlier version they will need to get the ClientID from the control into the JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

make sure you put the code in `document.ready` as below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select[ID$='ChildOrganizationDropDownList']").find("option").each(function(){   
         if($(this).text() === "------- Internal -------"){
            this.disabled  = true;
         }
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I would advise you to rather provide support for 2 latest IE version rather than supporting IE8.

I tested the following code and it works fine.

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var valinp="------- Internal -------";
        $("#ChildOrganizationDropDownList option[value='" 
            +  valinp + "']").attr("disabled","");

    })
```

As you are supporting IE 8 you should include a jquery version which is < jQuery 2.x
https://jquery.com/browser-support/

Answer (score 1):

Actualy in ASP.net Webform architecture is also matter where you write your jQuery / javascript.

if you are adding script in your aspx page where control is place. you can use `'<%= Control.ClientID %>'` to get current if of control. If you are placing your code in aspx page but in header and your control is in your child page  you can use

```
<%= Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("Button1").ClientID %>'

  var currentControlID='<%= Control.ClientID %>';
    $("#"+currentControlID+" option").each(function(){   
     if($(this).text() === "------- Internal -------"){
        this.disabled  = true;
         }
    });
```

If you have separate js file then you have to set ClientIDMode="Static" for control and assign you id(but make sure this id must not be used for any other control and it must be unique in page.).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the user to select that specific option why not hide it instead of disabling it?

```
$("#ChildOrganizationDropDownList option:contains('Internal')").hide();
```

Or even better remove it onclick of the object,

```
$(document).delegate("#ChildOrganizationDropDownList","click",function(){
    $(this).find("option:contains('Internal')").detach();
});
```

So they can't select it.

Comment: I am loading two set of values to the dropdown and i want to differentate between those

Answer (score 1):

If the value `-1` is never selectable accross your entire site then you can just do it very easily like this:

```
$('option[value=-1]').prop('disabled', true);
```

Otherwise you can do this:

1. Wrap your dropdown in `div` tags with an `id` (or you can also define a unique `class` and use it for all dropdowns with those properties):

   ```
   <div id="my-dropwdown">
       <asp:DropDownList ... />
   </div>
   ```
2. Select all the options inside the `div` with `value="-1"` and disable them:

   ```
   $('option[value=-1]', $('#my-dropdown')).prop('disabled', true);
   ```

   or

   ```
   $('option[value=-1]', $('#my-dropdown')).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   ```

   and if you want to select over the class:

   ```
   $('option[value=-1]', $('.subContractingControls')).prop('disabled', true);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me

```
$("#sel option[value=---Internal---]").prop('disabled','disabled');
```

Working JS Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/jt47kj5n/1/

You can also try by wrapping the value with single quotes.

```
$("#sel option[value='---Internal---']").prop('disabled','disabled');
```